# How to access Google Cloud Storage Buckets and its objects using a PHP Api

Tags: php, cloud, storage, google-cloud-storage, google-play-developer-api

First of all, I'm a Fresher php developer and i'm required by my product based company to automate the install and uninstall reports of their Android app which are available on Play Developers console.

I have created a Service account and i'm following the steps given in the following documentation([Here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6135870?p=financial_export&rd=1#export)) but somehow i'm stuck somewhere and i can't seem to move forward with it. I want to fetch the data of app installs and uninstalls on a regular basis.

I installed the google client php api library as follows which i got from Github [here](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) -

```
include __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
```

Now, on the cloud storage examples they have mentioned something like this -

```
include __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php'; 

use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;
```

and using this i'm getting the following error -

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient' >not found in /home/USERNAME/public_html/appreport/report/index.php:31 >Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in >/home/USERNAME/public_html/appreport/report/index.php on line 31

It would be really great if someone could help me with this

Answer (score 0):

Have you properly installed the storage client using composer? Per this page:

```
https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.122.0/storage/readme
```

That would be my guess.